# Variables scoped outside a for loop changing value to 0 unprompted

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio

I hope the language in the title is descriptive enough. Any suggestions for better language would be appreciated, as well as answers to my issue.

More detail: I have a function that populates a List with values calculated in a for loop, with the loop position being the only variance between iterations. When I run this function for the first time, two variables that are set *outside* the loop, seemingly at a random position (it changes every time) in my loop will change their value to 0 without being prompted to do so. These variables are not referenced anywhere else in all the code of my app.

Here is the entire function code. The line where this happens has an arrow, and the two variables mentioned are dmgModifier and attModifier.

```
    private void generateDps() {
        final float DEFENSE_DMG_REDUCTION_CAP = 0.9f;
        final int MAX_ENEMY_DEFENSE = 150;

        int realAtt = statTotals.getAttBonus();
        int realDex = statTotals.getDexBonus();
        double dexModifier = 1.0;
        double attModifier = 1.0;
        double dmgModifier = 1.0;

        // turns on status effects
        if(activeEffects[0]) {  // Damaging
            attModifier = 1.25;
        }
        if(activeEffects[1]) {  // Berserk
            dexModifier = 1.25;
        }
        if(activeEffects[2]) {  // Curse
            dmgModifier = 1.25;
        }
        if(activeEffects[3]) {  // Dazed (cancels berserk and sets dex to 0)
            dexModifier = 1;
            realDex = 0;
        }
        if(activeEffects[4]) {  // Weak (cancels damaging and sets att to 0)
            attModifier = 1;
            realAtt = 0;
        }

        loadoutDps = new ArrayList<>();
        double baseDmg = ((weapon.getAvgDamage() - 0.5) * (0.5 + realAtt / 50.0));
        double minimumDmg = Math.round(baseDmg * (1 - DEFENSE_DMG_REDUCTION_CAP)) * dmgModifier * attModifier;
        double finalRof = (1.5 + 6.5 * (realDex / 75.0)) * dexModifier * weapon.getRateOfFire();
        Log.i("DpsCalc", "Rof: " + finalRof);
        int noOfShots = weapon.getNoOfShots();
        Log.i("DpsCalc", "Shots: " + noOfShots);
        for(int currentDefense = 0; currentDefense <= MAX_ENEMY_DEFENSE; currentDefense++) {   // Generate a table row for every defense level up to the max
            double finalDps;
            Log.i("DpsCalc", "Current defense: " + currentDefense);

            if(weapon.getAttribute() == 0) {          // defense is a factor
    ----->      double currentDmg = Math.round(baseDmg - currentDefense) * dmgModifier * attModifier;
                Log.i("DpsCalc", "[Base shot damage: " + baseDmg + "] [Damage modifier: " + dmgModifier + "] [Attack modifier: " + attModifier + "] [Calculated shot damage: " + currentDmg + ']');

                double finalDamage = Math.max(
                        currentDmg,     // shot damage minus enemy defense rounded, multiplied by curse and damaging/weak modifiers
                        minimumDmg      // minimum shot damage due to defense reduction cap
                );
                Log.i("DpsCalc", "Final shot damage: " + finalDamage);
                finalDps = finalDamage * noOfShots * finalRof;
                Log.i("DpsCalc", "Final dps: " + finalDps);
            }
            else {    // defense factor removed (armor piercing)
                finalDps = Math.round(baseDmg) * dmgModifier * attModifier * noOfShots * finalRof;
            }
            loadoutDps.add(new DpsEntry(finalDps, loadoutId));
        }
    }
```

The logs look like this at the position where the values switch to 0

```
Current defense: 26
    [Base shot damage: 451.36] [Damage modifier: 1.0] [Attack modifier: 1.0] [Calculated shot damage: 425.0]
    Final shot damage: 425.0
I/DpsCalc: Final dps: 2545.608333333333
    Current defense: 27
I/DpsCalc: [Base shot damage: 451.36] [Damage modifier: 1.0] [Attack modifier: 1.0] [Calculated shot damage: 424.0]
    Final shot damage: 424.0
    Final dps: 2539.6186666666667
    Current defense: 28
I/DpsCalc: [Base shot damage: 451.36] [Damage modifier: 0.0] [Attack modifier: 0.0] [Calculated shot damage: 0.0]
    Final shot damage: 45.0
    Final dps: 269.53499999999997
    Current defense: 29
I/DpsCalc: [Base shot damage: 451.36] [Damage modifier: 0.0] [Attack modifier: 0.0] [Calculated shot damage: 0.0]
I/DpsCalc: Final shot damage: 45.0
I/DpsCalc: Final dps: 269.53499999999997
```

My question is thus: why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

***Update:*** I discovered this consistently only happens in the *first* `Loadout` object of an array (`generateDps()` is a method of `Loadout`).

Oddly enough, if I change the *weapon*, then cause this function to be executed again, the issue sometimes stays and sometimes doesn't. If I change any other piece of gear though, the issue doesn't happen. I'll reiterate: the variables that are randomly changing ***are not referenced anywhere else*** in all the code aside from what you can see here.

If you think seeing more of the code would help, just ask to see a part. My app is quite large so posting it all isn't really an option.

Comment: Interesting problem! Where is this print statement, ```I/DpsCalc:``` coming from? It appears to show up at random. Perhaps you are manipulating the ```dmgModifier/attModifier``` there. Another question worth asking is, Do they always turn to zero at the third iteration or is it random? I have tried to reproduce your error locally and I was unable to. I ran the same code switching out the variables with a broad scope for dummy values and with switched out log statements.

Comment: @berlin The `I/DpsCalc:` logs are from the `Log.i()` calls inside the loop, which wouldn't have any effect on the variables. Also note this is not the 3rd iteration, it's the `currentDefense`th iteration, in this case the 28th. And like I said in the post, the position where this happens changes each time

Comment: what i would do is make the ```dmgModifier``` and ```attModifier``` final when initializing them to 1 and then run the program. One of two things will occur, there will be an error produced when the values are being reassigned(wherever that may be), or no error occurs. In which case, you should check if there is another value being used instead.

Comment: @berlin Good idea, but it didn't give me much info, sadly. I set them as final and commented out the places where their value changes. They stayed at 1 for the whole loop, but I got no error. Every line in the whole program's code where those variables are referenced is shown in my question post (I checked). None of those set their values to 0, and none of them are even accessible from inside the loop. I am truly lost

Comment: 'They stayed at 1 for the whole loop' - does that mean the values of ```dmgModifier``` and ```attModifier``` did not change to zero and the expected values showed up? which essentially means we are trying to understand how it was changing before?

Comment: Yes, but only because I changed them to `final` to test